# Create customize email templates in Sitecore

Tags: html, templates, sitecore

I need to create a custom email template. I was thinking if we can create an renderings and have a data template created along and then create a content item with this as email the html body as an newsletter in Sitecore.

How can I achieve this? I want to get an HTML response in with all the data populated and then assign this html response to the email body and send it across.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at:

```
 Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage("[YourWebPage]");
```

This executes the webpage and returns the HTML as string. As far as I understand this is what you are trying to achieve.